# R dplyr & lubridate to subset

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

Both of my attempts at subsetting are not working below.

I am attempting to use the code below to return rows where the first collection time of the day (0,1), per id (1,2), is greater than or equal to 6am:

```
#structure data
sub <- read.csv("sub.csv", head =T)
sub$time <- format(strptime(sub$time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), format="%H:%M")
sub$time <- parse_date_time(sub$time, orders = c("HM"))

#parse
dft <- sub %>% 
    group_by(id, day) %>%
    filter(nth(tsw, 1) >= '0000-01-01 06:00:00') %>%
    ungroup()
```

I am attempting to use the code below to return rows where tsw[2] (time since waking), per id (1,2), per day (0,1) is greater than or equal to 0.5:

```
sub <- sub %>% 
    group_by(id, day) %>%
    filter(., nth(tsw, 2) >= 0.5) %>%
    ungroup()
```

data:

```
id,day,time,tsw
1,0,0000-01-01 05:00:00,0
1,0,0000-01-01 07:30:00,0.4
1,0,0000-01-01 12:00:00,5
1,0,0000-01-01 17:00:00,10
1,0,0000-01-01 21:00:00,14
1,1,0000-01-01 07:00:00,0
1,1,0000-01-01 07:30:00,0.5
1,1,0000-01-01 12:00:00,5
1,1,0000-01-01 17:00:00,10
1,1,0000-01-01 21:00:00,14
2,0,0000-01-01 07:00:00,0
2,0,0000-01-01 07:30:00,0.5
2,0,0000-01-01 12:00:00,5
2,0,0000-01-01 17:00:00,10
2,0,0000-01-01 21:00:00,14
2,1,0000-01-01 07:00:00,0
2,1,0000-01-01 07:30:00,0.5
2,1,0000-01-01 12:00:00,5
2,1,0000-01-01 17:00:00,10
2,1,0000-01-01 21:00:00,14
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to recreated your dataset, and then I did this:

```
data <- read.csv(file="data.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
data1 <-  ddply(filter(data, tsw >= 0.5),~ id + day)
```

[image]

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Close but not exactly. Your solution is also removing the 7am observations from each day within id, which I'd like to keep.

Comment: I would need something like this but it does not work: `ddply(filter(sub, nth(tsw, 2) >= 0.5), ~ id + day)`